# How can I call fmt::literals::operator""_format on a string literal defined in a macro?

Tags: c++, c++20

**Motivation:** I want to leverage the static (compile-time) error checking for string formatting from `_format` but cannot call it normally. My ideal solution would be a macro that will validate a static format string literal and the associated arguments, such as:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
using namespace fmt::literals;

#define ENSURE_VALID(message, ...) message##_format(__VA_ARGS__)

// Examples
ENSURE_VALID("{} {}", 4, 5); // Will compile fine
ENSURE_VALID("{} {}", 3); // Will fail during compilation because not enough
                          // arguments were passed for the format string
```

**Problem:** The above implementation works for normal situations, but fails when the format string is defined elsewhere:

```
#define FMT_STR "{} {}"

ENSURE_VALID(FMT_STR, 4, 5); // Fails to compile
```

Calling `ENSURE_VALID` with `FMT_STR` fails because the preprocessor evaluates `ENSURE_VALID` before `FMT_STR`, resulting in `FMT_STR_format`, which is not expanded correctly.

***What I am looking for:*** an implementation of `ENSURE_VALID` that correctly handles defined strings like `FMT_STR`.

Comment: As you can tell from @Barry's valid answer, you just need to use standard C preprocessor voodoo here... nothing particular to C++20 or fmt.

Answer (score 3):

The usual solution here is just to use another macro:

```cpp
#define ENSURE_VALID2(message, ...) message##_format(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENSURE_VALID(message, ...) ENSURE_VALID2(message, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Just passing through `message` will allow it to properly expand inside of `ENSURE_VALID2`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to append `""` to the message string, creating:

`#define ENSURE_VALID(message, ...) message""_format(__VA_ARGS__)`